# Macs Claiming "This certificate has expired" After SSL Key update on a 2003 Exchange Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003, mac

For some reason after we updated our certificate on the Exchange 2003 server and the time for the certificate to expire passed all mac users started to receive the error with Entourage 2006(I think) "This certificate has expired" and it shows the old expiration date.

No Windows users are getting cert errors and if I visit the site and view the cert it shows the proper, updated expiration date.

Is there something I need to do on the Macs to get them to see the new cert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out. Older versions of Entourage require that the root certificate be imported in. This can be done under the certificate manager and by visiting the outlook web access and downloading the cert.